# Как избавиться от двойного цикла и оптимизировать алгоритм пересечения 3D объектов?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Подскажите как оптимизировать данный алгоритм. Загружаю объект(у меня около 20 объектов. каждый раз вызываю функцию loadObj, приведенную ниже), каждый объект кладу в пустой массив objectsARRAY. Потом делаю двойной цикл и ищу пересечения объекта со всеми остальными. Очень мне не нравится такой подход. При этом еще нужно учитывать, что может не быть пересечений и не сравнивать объект с самим собой.

В целом мне нужно найти есть ли пересечения. Если есть пересечение, то вызывать еще один метод, где будет другая логика.

```
export const loadObj = path => {
this.THREE = THREE;
const container = new THREE.Object3D();
container.loaded = false;
const loader = new FBXLoader();

loader.load(
    path,
    object => {
        container.loaded = true;
        container.add(object);
        objectsARRAY.push(object);
    }
);
setTimeout(() => {
    let next = true;

    while (next) {
        for (let i = 0; i < objectsARRAY.length || !next; i++) {
            const currentObj = objectsARRAY[i];
            const currentBB = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(currentObj);
            if (i === objectsARRAY.length - 1) {
                break;
            }
            for (let j = i + 1; j < objectsARRAY.length; j++) {
                const compareObj = objectsARRAY[j];
                const compareBB = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(compareObj);

                if (currentBB.isIntersectionBox(compareBB)) {
                    next = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, 0);

return container;
```

};

Помогите переписать

Comment: Я прям даже не знаю с чего начать. А объекты загружаемые - они все разные 20 штук, или один и тот же, просто 20 загружается?

Comment: разные. для каждого объекта вызываем эту функцию

Comment: я бы реализовал как тут http://www.geofx.com/graphics/nehe-three-js/lessons25-32/lesson30/lesson30.html

но у меня объекты и я не могу получить доступ к  mesh.geometry.vertices.length

Comment: Это потому, что загрузчик возвращает меш с геометрией типа `THREE.BufferGeometry()` и вершины геометрии надо искать в буферном атрибуте `position`, например `object.geometry.attributes.position`. Как работать с буферными атрибутами - посмотрите [здесь](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/BufferAttribute).

Comment: Так у меня вообще нет в свойства свойства geometry.

у меня Object3D

Comment: вот https://pastenow.ru/1c31ef45b318bb45aebb0079db7fd741

Comment: а что в свойстве `.children` у этого объекта?

Comment: Нашел! Спасибо за наводку

а если у меня в свойстве position 
вот такая картина координат

https://pastenow.ru/a51584f9f5a49afa591b5e403d112395

Comment: что с этим делать тогда?(
в то время как у просто меша (куб, сфера и т.д.)
вот такие 

https://pastenow.ru/46c25aad8b1e28457146da36b0570ce8

Comment: А они в примере их все перебирают получается
в методе checkObjectCollisions
https://github.com/rkwright/geofx_site/blob/master/graphics/nehe-three-js/lessons25-32/lesson30/lesson30webgl.html

Comment: Могу ли я тогда искать пересечения просто через isIntersectionBox как вверху делала, без векторов?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75182/discussion-between-werty-and-prisoner849).

Answer (score 0):

Судя по использованию неких Box, достаточно проверять пересечение ограничивающих параллелепипедов. В таком случае стоит использовать пространственные структуры данных, например, [R-tree](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_(%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85))

[произвольно выбранный пример js реализации](https://github.com/Eronana/rbush-3d)